# How can I copy values of one column into another while changing value of column 2?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I am writing a ASP.NET web app and the customers want to be able to 'clone' a user's group codes to a new user_code.

I have a table `userGroup` with 2 columns `group_code` and `user_code`.

By cloning, I want to get all `group_code` where the `user_code = 'testUser'` and copy all of those `group_code` to a new `user_code` 'testUser2'. I know I will need to use a parameter, but I'm not sure how to structure my query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want `insert`:

```
insert into userGroup(group_code, user_code)
    select group_code, 'testUser2'
    from userGroup
    where user_code = 'testUser';
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are thinking about a stored procedure, you can do like below

```
create proc copyGroupCodes(@sourceUser varchar, @targetUser varchar)
as
begin
Insert into userGroup(group_code, user_code)
select group_code, @targetUser  as user_code
 from userGroup 
where user_code = @sourceUser
end
```